# Python - List indexing

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm try to convert working Matlab code. This is what I have:

```
d=[0.004398047,0.123]
m=[0.071,0.123]
x=[]
indices=[1,2,3]
for i in indices:
   print(i)
   if d[i]==0.0:
     print (d[i])
     x.append(m[i])
   else:
    print('else',i)
    x.append(m[i]+d[i]* ny.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1))
```

Running it I get "IndexError: list index out of range". Why does this occur?

Comment: lists are indexed from 0....`0,1,2`, also `d` only has 2 elements so even with that fix you will get the same error

Comment: Sorry, I was stucked on a different error and I forgot to remove the third element from indices. I'll be back (as son as I'll wake up a little bit smarter) with a smarter question...Anyway thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is in the `indices` array.
The for loop starts from 0 and the `d` and `m` arrays only have 2 elements.
Modify the indices array with:

```
indices=[0,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The indexes of `d` range from `0` to `1`.  You are trying `1`, `2`, and `3`.